# Android Achartengine : how to change date labels on x-Axis to strings in ProjectStatusChart

Tags: android, achartengine

i am developing an android application using AChartEngine library and i am using PojectStatusChart but i am facing a problem with the x-Axis labels. it is set to dates an i want to change it to Strings but i don't know how to

can someone help me plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProjectStatusChart` is a time chart, so it has X axis labels as dates. You can either look at another example in the demo package or modify it from time chart to line chart for instance.